# empty error message in python

Tags: python, exception

I'm trying to debug an error, I got a "no exception supplied" when I ran it initially and then later put in a try/except block to print out whatever the error was.

```
try:
    #some code
except BaseException, e:
    print str(e)
```

This produces a blank line of output, any ideas what it could be?

EDIT: Sorry, was hoping there was a specific reason that the error message could be blank.  There is no stack trace output which is what caused me to be forced to do a try/except block in first place, I'm still programming this thing so I'm just letting the 'compiler' catch the errors for now.  The actual code that's throwing the error is in a Django app so it'll have some functions from Django.

```
try:
    if len(request.POST['dateToRun']) <= 0:
        dateToRun = Job.objects.filter(id=jobIDs[i]).values()['whenToRun'].split(' ')[0]
    if len(request.POST['timeToRun']) <= 0:
        timeToRun = Job.objects.filter(id=jobIDs[i]).values()['whenToRun'].split(' ')[1]
except BaseException, e:
    print str(e)
```

This is code in a view function.  jobIDs is a dict containing value key pairs in the format ##Selection: ## (ie 17Selection: 17).  Sorry I forgot to post this initially.

EDIT: repr(e) has given me TypeError() which is better than not knowing anything.

Comment: Maybe we can help you better if you give us the stack trace output and the actual code.

Answer (score 22):

This means the exception has no message attached. Print the exception *type*:

```
print repr(e)
```

You may also want to print the traceback:

```
import traceback

# ...
except BaseException as e:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

You want to *avoid* catching `BaseException` however, this is no better than a blanket `except:` statement. Catch more specific exceptions instead.

Answer (score 7):

The following produces a blank line of output:

```
try:
    raise Exception()
except BaseException, e:
    print str(e)
```

Use `repr(e)` to see what the exception is that was raised.

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```
try:
    #code
except BaseException as e:
    print str(e)
```

This seems to be the easiest to understand, and affective.

Answer (score 1):

Put the try/except block around smaller sections of code until you find the offending line. For example, if you have:

```
try:
    a = fn(b)
    c = fn(a)
except BaseException, e:
    print str(e)
```

Then change it to:

```
a = fn(b)
try:
    c = fn(a)
except BaseException, e:
    print str(e)
```